# A flight website offered me change/cancellation for a fee, now refuses and blames airline

Tags: bookings, cancellations, flight-search-engines, refunds

I recently used a website (mytrip.com) to book a round-trip flight (with 1 stop in each direction). The website I used for booking is not the airline's own website. Now, I was not sure I would actually want the exact date I was booking, but I noticed I was being offered a 'premium package' for an extra fee, in which I could edit the flight details or cancel at no charge.

And, indeed, I ended up having to do that several days later; I needed to postpone my return by 2 or 3 days (the return flight is in two weeks from now). When I asked to do so, the website/company-behind-the-website told me it would not be possible, since the airlines does not permit changes or cancellations. I told them that they sold me that option, and they claimed I should have read the fine print. Actually that fine print was sent to me in Dutch, but even disregarding that fact, they can't sell you an "option to do X" and have the fine print say "you can't do X"... I would think.

So, my question is - is there anything I can do about it? I'm not averse to paying extra (obviously, not the price of a new ticket) to make a change, but nobody seems to be willing to allow me to make it.

Notes:

- I called the airline directly; they said that because my ticket is in a cheap fare category, they will absolutely under no circumstances allow any changes, even if it the flight I want was coming up and they had empty seats they weren't going to fill.
- If legal jurisdiction is an issue somehow, I live in the Netherlands and the flight I want to change is from TLV to AMS.
- If you need more information in order to be able to give an answer, ask.

Comment: This is a legal issue. It's called [false advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_advertising). If what you are saying is true and you have documentation, you can take legal action in the country with jurisdiction however that is a long route. You need to have documentation. What does the airlines own fine print say, not the website, the airline itself? You might be able to collect against the airline itself using agency laws. Do you have a travel ombudsman in Netherlands?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the payment page?

Comment: Not to make your day any worse but did you notice that _[This Website](http://www.mytrip.com/terms-and-conditions) is operated by a Greek entity and this Agreement is governed by the laws of Greece/EU. You hereby consent to the exclusive jurisdiction and venue of courts in Athens, Greece, in all disputes arising out of or relating to the use of this Website. Use of this Website is unauthorized in any jurisdiction that does not give effect to all provisions of these terms and conditions, including, without limitation, this paragraph._

Comment: @SheikPaul you are wrong, the airline is absolutely not at fault here. They sell you a contract with conditions and what the agent does is their business. For example, there is legit insurance for cancellation or for connection misses and so forth. It is absolutely possible someone could sell a "modify flight" insurance package but the risk might make it tooe xpensive.

Comment: This website is part of a well know ring of scammers http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/online-travel-booking-bidding-agencies/1562307-airtickets-com-scam-website.html all owned by the same travel agency.

Comment: @chx: Well, it's not a scam in the sense that I do have the ticket for the date and times I booked. Are you sure about that? Your link regards airlinetrips.com.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Will try to obtain that.

Comment: @SheikPaul: I don't know what the airline's own fine print says; I'll look it up - but I bought something from mytrip.com, not from the airline. They told me what I'm buying, they collected my money and they agree or disagree to make a change or a cancellation.

Comment: @einpoklum The reason I asked to check the airline fine print is there just might be something about their liability or lack thereof when their ticket is purchased through an authorized reseller. What you are looking for right now is a solution, **regardless** of whether it's the airline or mytrip which provides the solution.

Comment: @Dorothy: I wonder if these kinds of one-sided conditions really apply. After all, they can write anything in those terms and agreements. I'm assuming such consumers' rights issues are adjudicable wherever you live, if the company has a presence in that country. Of course, they might not have, in which case I am indeed kind of screwed.

Comment: @SheikPaul: Ok, I'll do it.

Comment: @einpoklum oh rest assured all those "one sided" conditions apply. Take a look at my recent [reply](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87812/4188) explaining what an airline ticket is.

Comment: @chx: In the state I'm from, there's special legislation regarding these kinds of contracts, and they are automatically in question; courts often declare them void (for all customers, not just for an individual based on specific circumstances). This is particularly strong w.r.t. venue, where a customer's right to sue is provided for by law and cannot be waived by contract (well, this is sort of true, I haven't studied case law on this matter.)

Comment: @chx: Also, the question you linked to regards the case of buying a ticket from an airline. I have a contract with mytrip.com (AFAICT anyway).

Comment: Any chance you can share the details of that 'premium package' somewhere, or perhaps even better: the fine print you were sent? I can't really find much on them on their website, and other sources only seem to mention them in the context of speeding up customer service response times.

Comment: Also consider taking it up with your credit card company.

Comment: @Calchas: I paid using direct debit (Netherlands' iDeal).